# How to enable administrator role

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have Drupal 7.22 with "minimal" install profile.

When I create new user, I have disabled option in "Administration role".
How can I enable administrator role for new user?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create at least one role (maybe call it "Administrator") and it will show up in the dropdown. (The 2 default roles don't count)

Answer (score 0):

you can create anew role and give all privilege (edit,add,remove ..Etc) and give it to new user

Answer (score 0):

Execute this PHP code in the devil module (taken from the file \drupal-site\profiles\standard\standard.install):

```
// Create a default role for site administrators, with all available permissions assigned.
$admin_role = new stdClass();
$admin_role->name = 'administrator';
$admin_role->weight = 2;
user_role_save($admin_role);
user_role_grant_permissions($admin_role->rid, array_keys(module_invoke_all('permission')));
// Set this as the administrator role.
variable_set('user_admin_role', $admin_role->rid);

// Assign user 1 the "administrator" role.
db_insert('users_roles')
->fields(array('uid' => 1, 'rid' => $admin_role->rid))
->execute();
```